# Loading data from Oracle into Excel via ADODB - performance issue

Tags: oracle, excel, vba, excel-2007, adodb

We have a large Excel application which uses VBA, named ranges, ADODB. It's primary function is to connect to Oracle, load a dataset into Excel, allow the user to edit it and save it back to Oracle. The application is in Excel 2003 but we have been meaning to upgrade to Excel 2007 for a while. We're now faced with a 'too many formats' error when pasting into the Excel 2003 app, and this is a good reason as any to upgrade.

After saving the Excel 2003 as Excel 2007 and running the Oracle load VBA, data takes about twice as long to load. We can actually see the records being loaded whereas in the Excel 2003 version, the records in the sheet just zipped down the page.

So my first objective is to improve this performance. There are two ways I can do this:

1. Work out why Excel 2007 is slower than Excel 2003 and fix it
2. Improve the data loading routine

On item 1, I am interested in anyone else who can shed some light on why it would take longer to do this in 2007 vs 2003

On item 2 I am considering converting the recordset to a string using GetString and pasting it onto the sheet (rather than adding it one cell at a time). I am also interested in anyone who has done this before.

Some sanitised code of the transfer from ADODB to Excel sheet code is below:

```
While Not RECSET.EOF
  ' loop thru columns returned in sql row
  sExtractRec = ""
  For i = 1 To Column_Names.Count
    vColumnName = Column_Names(i)
    vItem = RECSET(vColumnName) 
    vItem = formatIfDate(vItem, vColumnName) ' format if a date or datetime
    currCell.Value = vItem
    Set currCell = currCell.Offset(0, 1)
    If Not isNull(vItem) Then
          vItem = IIf(vItem = "", "", Replace(vItem, ";", " "))
    End If
    sExtractRec = sExtractRec & vItem & ";"
  Next i
  Set currCell = currCell.Offset(1, 0 - Column_Names.Count) ' goto first cell next row
  iRowCnt = iRowCnt + 1
  RECSET.MoveNext

  If bWriteExtractFile Then
      Print #iExtractFile, sExtractRec
  End If
Wend
```

Comment: Have you tried turning off screenupdating and setting claculation to manual while populating the sheet?  I'm guessing not since you mentioned watching the records get populated line-by-line.

Comment: That appears to have speeded things up considerably, thanks! I made the assumption that the original author already thought of this stuff. Now I have the issue that drop down's are populating with blanks. I'll need to look into this further, I may post a further question in this thread if that's OK.

Comment: @Tim Williams, if you post that comment as an answer I will accept it, as it solved my immediate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try turning off screenupdating and setting calculation to manual while populating the sheet.

I'm guessing you're not doing this now, since you mentioned watching the records get populated line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `CopyFromRecordset` method tends to be far faster than manually populating cells. Example usage:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordSet RECSET`

The date/datetime formatting issues could presumably be fixed after the data has been copied to the worksheet.

More details about this method are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223288%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Excellent, thank you for that suggestion. I have managed to improve performance drastically by turning off screenupdating. I imagine this tip will improve things even further. Right now I am struggling with that I think is a 'too many formats' issue though.

Comment: Although this is very helpful, the other answer directly solved my issue. Thanks anyway.